# Rails adjust params and class based on current params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 6. I have the following in my view:

```
    <% @searchable_types.each do |obj| %>
      <% if params[:type] == obj.searchable_type %>
        <a href="<%= search_path(q: params[:q]) %>" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border rounded-pill active"><%= obj.searchable_type %></a>
      <% else %>
        <a href="<%= search_path(q: params[:q], type: obj.searchable_type) %>" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border rounded-pill"><%= obj.searchable_type %></a>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

What this code achieves as a toggle filter is:

1. Remove param in the `search_path` if it's already active
2. Add param in the `search_path` if it's not active

The code is certainly not elegant. How can I adjust the `search_path` params without using such explicit conditional statement?

Answer (score 0):

Not better, but avoiding duplication:

```rb
<%
  link_class        = 'btn btn-outline-secondary border rounded-pill'
  active_link_class = "#{link_class} active"
%>
<% @searchable_types.each do |obj| %>
  <%
    is_active   = params[:type] == obj.searchable_type
    link_params = { q: params[:q] }
    link_params.merge!(type: obj.searchable_type) unless is_active
  %>
  <%= link_to search_path(link_params), obj.searchable_type, class: is_active ? active_link_class : link_class %>
<% end %>
```